# datalist TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null

Tags: reactjs

On a react project I'm getting :

```
DOMLazyTree.js:70 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null
    at Function.replaceChildWithTree (DOMLazyTree.js:70)
    at Object.dangerouslyReplaceNodeWithMarkup (Danger.js:42)
    at Object.dangerouslyReplaceNodeWithMarkup [as replaceNodeWithMarkup] (DOMChildrenOperations.js:122)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._replaceNodeWithMarkup (ReactCompositeComponent.js:781)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:771)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js:721)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:642)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:544)
    at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js:126)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:751)
```

When I try to load a page to which i added a datalist

Any clue where to start looking ?

Comment: Code showing your initial components that are being rendered would be great otherwise we are in the dark here.

Answer (score 1):

If using redux-thunk, ensure that the error is not swallowed by a promise.

We had a similar problem where calling `dispatch` synchronously called our reducers, and React synchronously rerendered.  In our render, an error was raise when passing children to an `<input />` which bubbled up in our thunk.

In other words, the real error message was displayed with the actions in the console.